# Swift return string from Array

Tags: arrays, macos, swift

I'm trying to get a random name from this Array as a string instead of a number.

I.E: The array normally returns a random number 0 through 9, I'd rather have it return the string that 0 through 9 represents like Preston or James instead of the number itself.

The code below is broken, but I hope it lets you see what I'm trying to do.

```
 var firstName : [String] = ["Preston", "Ally", "James", "Justin", "Dave", "Bacon", "Bossy",     "Edward", "Edweird" ]

var standardIdent = "First Name:\(firstName[random(0...9)]) Last Name:\(lastName[random(0...5)]) \n Age:\(rand())"
println(standardIdent)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `arc4random` like:

```
let firstRandom = Int(arc4random() % 10)
let secondRandom = Int(arc4random() % 6)
var standardIdent = "First Name:\(firstName[firstRandom]) Last Name:\(lastName[secondRandom]) \n Age:\(rand())"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `arc4random()` with `%` operator. That introduces a [modulo bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modulo_bias).

In Swift 4.2 and later, you should use `randomElement()`:

```
let firstNames = ["Preston", "Ally", "James", "Justin", "Dave", "Bacon", "Bossy", "Edward", "Edweird"]
let randomFirstName = firstNames.randomElement()!
```

Or, if the array could possibly be empty, don't use the forced unwrapping operator, but instead do:

```
guard let randomFirstName = firstNames.randomElement() else {
    print("array was empty")
    return
}
```

In Swift versions prior to 4.2, you should:

1. You should generally use `arc4random_uniform`, not `arc4random`, to eliminate modulo bias.
2. You should probably use the count of the items in the array to determine the range of possible index values.

Thus:

```
guard firstNames.count > 0 else { ... }
let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstNames.count)))
let randomFirstName = firstNames[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

Even better: use `arc4random_uniform` to avoid modulo bias:

```
var firstName : [String] = ["Preston", "Ally", "James", "Justin", "Dave", "Bacon", "Bossy", "Edward", "Edweird" ]

var lastName : [String] = ["Miller", "Jones", "Jackson", "Smith"]

let firstRandom = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstName.count)))
let secondRandom = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lastName.count)))
var standardIdent = "First Name:\(firstName[firstRandom]) Last Name:\(lastName[secondRandom]) \n Age:\(rand())"
```